# Numerator of HRRN scheduling formula

Tags: operating-systems, process-scheduling

In the HRRN scheduling, priority formula is

P = (W+E)/E , where W: waiting time and E: estimated run time.

CPU finds the job that has highest priority value and does that job.

However, the formula is equivalent to P = 1 + W/E. If we just "minus 1" and make a new formula P' = W/E, the order of jobs does not change.

So the question is, why do we use P = (W+E)/E rather than P' = W/E? Is there any specific reason (like P must be greater than 1)? Or are they just using the original formula since it was made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either formula, since as you mention, the resulting algorithms are completely equivalent. The reasoning behind the standard formula $(W+E)/E$ is that it is the ratio between the *expected completion time* to the *expected running time*. Presumably when the algorithm was first suggested, the expected completion time was denoted by its own variable.